# jQuery - Random elements showing for a certain time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

I want to make a `div` where one element of the `div` are randomly changing after a short period of time (i.e.: THIS IS **PARIS**, THIS IS **AN APPLE** etc.)

I have this line of HTML:

```
<div id="A">
  THIS IS
</div>

<div id="B">
  <div>AN APPLE</div>
  <div>PARIS</div>
  <div>PICASSO</div>
</div>
```

This is the code that i used before, but now i want to use different divs instead of arrays.

```
var textarray = [
 "AN APPLE",
 "PARIS",
 "PICASSO"
];

function RndText() {
  var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);
  document.getElementById('B').innerHTML=textarray[rannum];
}
onload = function() { RndText(); }
var inter = setInterval(function() { RndText(); }, 1000);
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide your jquery code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `Math.random` and `setInterval`. Snippet below:

```js
$(function() {
  var n = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
      n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
      $("#B div").hide();
      $("#B").find('div:eq('+n+')').show();
  },500);
});
```

```css
#B div:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A">
  THIS IS
</div>

<div id="B">
  <div>AN APPLE</div>
  <div>PARIS</div>
  <div>PICASSO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, thank you very much @GuruprasadRao ! Is it possible to turn off the fading?

Comment: just use `show()` instead of `fadeIn(200)` inside `setInterval`

Comment: Thank you very much @GuruprasadRao ! Brilliant!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Two quick question!
I don't want to repeat the words. Is it possible somehow?
What if i want these words change on click?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you.. Random number doesn't guarantee you about repetition.. If you want them to change on click, then move `setInterval` code within your click event. For detailed answer, you might need to ask separate question.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put div text in array and use `Math.random()` to return random element and add it to `#A`.

```js
$("#B").hide();
var text = $('#A').text();

var words = $("#B div").map(function() {
  return $(this).text()
}).get();

setInterval(function() {
  $('#A').text(text + ' ' + words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]);
}, 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A">
  THIS IS
</div>

<div id="B">
  <div>AN APPLE</div>
  <div>PARIS</div>
  <div>PICASSO</div>
</div>
```

Instead of using arrays you can also directly take text from random `#B div` element using `eq()`.

```js
$("#B").hide();
var text = $('#A').text();

setInterval(function() {
  $('#A').text(text + ' ' + $('#B div').eq([Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#B div').length)]).text());
}, 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A">
  THIS IS
</div>

<div id="B">
  <div>AN APPLE</div>
  <div>PARIS</div>
  <div>PICASSO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't want to use arrays, that's what i did before! Any other suggestion @NenadVracar?

Comment: I don't really want to use plain text always (in some div i want links, pictures, etc.), maybe a hide/show solution would be better, what do you think? How can i achieve that @NenadVracar?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, similar functionality, but uses [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) with function as parameter to select the element to show

```
setInterval(function(){
  $("#B div").hide();
    $("#B div").eq(function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * $("#B div").length);
  }()).show();
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need this code

```
<div id="A"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myArray = ['AN APPLE','PARIS','PICASSO'];
  setInterval(function(){
    var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
    $('#A').html('THIS IS '+rand);
  },1000);  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't want to use arrays, that's what i did before! Any other suggestion @DevSullo?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.  Hope this helps.

```
<html>
   <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js">    </script>
    <script>
    fruit = new Array("A Pear", "A strawberry", "An orange");
    cities = new Array("London", "New York", "Glasgow");
    artists = new Array("Monet", "Cezanne", "Da Vinci");

    changeValues = function(fruit, cities, artists) {
        var f = Math.floor((Math.random() * fruit.length-1) + 1);
        var c = Math.floor((Math.random() * cities.length-1) + 1);
        var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * artists.length-1) + 1);
        var things = "<div>" + fruit[f] + "</div><div>" + cities[c] + "</div><div>" + artists[a] + "</div>";
        $("#B").html(things);
        setTimeout(changeValues, 2500, fruit, cities, artists);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(changeValues, 2500, fruit, cities, artists);
    });

    </script>

   </head>
   <body>  
      <div id="A">
    THIS IS
      </div>
    <div id="B">
      <div>AN APPLE</div>
      <div>PARIS</div>
      <div>PICASSO</div>
    </div>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```